# Convert SOG to VGA using LM1881

Tags: video, vga

I need to convert RGsB (aka SOG or Sync On Green) to VGA. I've built the circuit as shown below:

[image]

The circuit works but the output picture looks quite striped, something like this image:

[image]

Any help in fixing this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: PeterJ: both links are fine, but first image has the same schematic as http://www.age.ne.jp/x/nrg/magazin/sog_adaptar.png

Comment: That forum probably needed registration to view the schematic, but I've just included them inline.

Comment: That clearly has nothing to do with the sync separator. You need to start looking at the individual signals with an oscilloscope in order to diagnose this.

Comment: Its because you didn't get rid of sync signal from green line. You need some more complicated circuit for removing sync signal from green (keeping only hsync and vsync). I don't know how to perform this.

Comment: Isn't your schematic converting VGA to SOG rather than the other way around? You have VGA on the left side, and the right side is labelled "out".

Comment: Can we have the board layout as well? How is it powered? Is the sync timing of the original signal weird?