# YPbPr to VGA (consoles on monitor)

Tags: components, adapter, vga

So the main idea is to take the component video of my consoles and convert them to VGA using the LM1881 IC, to strip the sync signal.
If I was going to plug the green cable from my PS2 component into this chip, for example, and then output to the VGA monitor, will it work or do I still need something else?
Consider the scheme below from this thread here: [Convert SOG to VGA using LM1881](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/153478/convert-sog-to-vga-using-lm1881)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, that won't work. That schematic is for stripping sync-on-green from an otherwise normal VGA signal.

Despite their colors, the three RCA connectors used for component video are **not** green, red, and blue components! They are Y, Pb, and Pr components. (Y is luma -- brightness -- and Pb and Pr are two axes of chroma -- color.) To convert these signals to VGA, you would need to:

- Perform a colorspace conversion from YPbPr to RGB, and
- Extract horizontal and vertical sync signals from the input.